# Flutter pubSec.yaml

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Error on line 77, column 5: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
╷
77 │     fonts:
│     ^

getting this error, check out the image I tried to add some font to the flutter file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtSX8.png)

please, check this image

I didn't get what to do.
Please help, with this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you indent the file correctly

Check the official doc for reference

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts